# Accelerate neighbor analysis in QGIS PostgreSQL / PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

For a project I have to show the relationship between 2 or more objects.
For this I use the code below in QGIS in step 1 I determine the relation in step 2 the items are counted.
In the test set I use 5128 objects here QGIS takes quite a long time, the original data set is more than 1 million objects.
I wonder would this also be possible in PostgreSQL / PostGIS to make the whole faster and reproducible?

Code for QGIS 3
Step 1

```py
aggregate(
 layer:= ‘Test',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:=Label,
 concatenator:=', ',
 filter:=touches($geometry, geometry(@parent))
 )
```

Step 2

```py
aggregate(
 layer:= ‘Test’,
 aggregate:='count',
 expression:=Label,
 filter:=touches($geometry, geometry(@parent))
 )
```

product

[image: Example]

[image: result]

In the result you can see that an (label) object has a relation with an other object 1 to N=(Count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can join and query the same layer: once for the "source", and one for the connected neighbors. Grouping by source ID will let you count the connected neighbors and will also open the door to [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).

A spatial index is required if you want a descent execution time.

```sql
SELECT a.id, count(*), string_agg(b.id::text,',') as neighbors
FROM test a JOIN test  b ON st_touches(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it with a test data set to see if it will work for me